# Multi-threading a for loop for bitmap coloring

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a loop in a program coloring a Bitmap. It looks about like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<1920; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 1080; j++){
        compute_pixel(i, j);
    }
}
```

I want to speed it up by using 8 cores of my CPU and give them different threads, one pixel each, so that when I already have 8 cores in use (working on first 8 pixels), I can assign the 9th pixel to the first core which has finished its job. What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: What about using a GPU for 'per-pixel work'? GPUs are embarrassingly more parallelized than CPUs for the work they can compute.

Comment: @user2864740 I guess that would be even better. I don't have much experience with it though

Comment: Make sure you have your loops the right way round so that you process adjacent pixels to make best use of caches. Don't process row 0 pixel 0 then row 1 pixel 0 which may be 1920x3 bytes away. Rather process row 0 pixel 0 then row 0 pixel 1 which is right next-door and will already be in cache.

Comment: @koman900 But now that's a different question - and hence why I voted as 'Too Broad'. The *'good'* use of concurrency depends a good bit on the specific problem domain / requirements. Or is this just a task in 'learning how to use threads and basic synchronization primitives'?

Comment: @user2864740 Well, I wouldn't say that is too broad, as the content of my question is quite specific and that is what answers i expected. The GPU is a different question indeed and that's why I would make a good use of a comment about that but I don't expect answers about GPU

Comment: OpenMP doesn't split your task how you describe, by the way. It doesn't give 8 pixels to 8 CPU cores and then give the next pixel to whichever one finishes first. Rather, it splits the 1920 rows into 8 and gives 1920/8 rows to the first core, and the second lot of 1920/8 rows to the second core...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a great candidate for the [OpenMP](https://www.openmp.org/) library. Here's an example of using it to parallelize a for loop:

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp for
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
  // do something with i
}
```

You can also use OpenMP with nested for loops. It may take a bit of setup to get running on your machine, but once you do it's surprisingly easy to use for tasks like this.

If you're interested in leveraging your GPU, look into [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/) and [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/).

Comment: @koman900 Isn't it great? Feel free to accept if this answers your question.